# Learning in C++/Waffles with object weights

Tags: c++, machine-learning, decision-tree, adaboost

I wonder if it is possible to pass object weights along with features in Waffles supervised learners (e.g. decision trees) for boosting purposes?

Comment: What do you mean by "boosting purposes"?

Comment: I mean that I'm going to use such trees in a composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible, but you could approximate weights by duplicating rows.